# css simple hover fade

Tags: css, image, transition, fade

Was just wandering if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong, trying to make one image fade to revealing another image beneath it whilst hovering. However, I cant seem to get the two images to overlap. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<div id="content" class="sixteen columns textcenter box">
<p>
       <img class="top" src="img/homepageimg2.jpg" alt="Photography Thumbnail" align="center"> 
       <img class="bottom" src="img/homepageimg22.jpg" alt="Photography Thumbnail" align="center">
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
z-index:10;
position:relative;
background-image:url(../img/backgroundindex.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;  
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom:50px;

}
#content img{
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#content img.top hover {
opacity:0;
}
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover is a psuedo, so if you want the effect to be applied when an img (child of #content) with the class 'top' is hovered over, you'll want to use the form:

```
#content img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Try using absolute positioning on both .top and .bottom (plus top:0, bottom:0, etc.), and relative positioning on their parent container. Make sure .top has a higher z-index than .bottom.

I've set up a complete demo of this effect on CodePen: http://cdpn.io/aAjBb

Demo HTML:

```
<div class="hover-swap">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg" class="top"/>
  <img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/tuxedo_kittens-256x256.jpg" class="bottom"/>
</div>
```

Demo CSS:

```
.hover-swap {
  position: relative;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.hover-swap .top {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover-swap .bottom {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-swap:hover .top {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hover-swap .bottom, .hover-swap .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```